# Selenium WebDriver is not selecting options from checkbox in HTML. Python 3

Tags: python

I'm developing something similar to a webscrapping to take informations from a website in html, but I'm having problems to select the options from the checkbox in the internet web page with selenium webdriver. (I'm using Python 3)

Check out part of the code:

```
driver.get('website_acessed')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="id_presented"]').click()

#this method is presenting this error:

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="id_presented"]"}
  (Session info: chrome = id_chrome)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x011A5FD3+2187219]
    Ordinal0 [0x0113E6D1+1763025]
    Ordinal0 [0x01053E78+802424]
    Ordinal0 [0x01081C10+990224]
    Ordinal0 [0x01081EAB+990891]
    Ordinal0 [0x010AEC92+1174674]
    Ordinal0 [0x0109CBD4+1100756]
    Ordinal0 [0x010ACFC2+1167298]
    Ordinal0 [0x0109C9A6+1100198]
    Ordinal0 [0x01076F80+946048]
    Ordinal0 [0x01077E76+949878]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x014490C2+2721218]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0143AAF0+2662384]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0123137A+526458]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01230416+522518]
    Ordinal0 [0x01144EAB+1789611]
    Ordinal0 [0x011497A8+1808296]
    Ordinal0 [0x01149895+1808533]
    Ordinal0 [0x011526C1+1844929]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75486739+25]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x775F90AF+1215]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x775F907D+1165]
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks for the attention!

Comment: What's the URL of the page you're trying to interact with ?  Looks like there's no element with id=id_presented in your page.

Comment: I'm sorry for being so late haha. I've used webdriverwait and ES for wait till the buttom appears in the screen as an operator part of the web page, so the script could identify and click on the buttom when it appears for it. It worked a lot! Thanks for the attention and help :)